# Weight property for text-view not effecting in activity when I put scroll-view in it?

Tags: android, xml

My XML file I have Problem with the text view weight Property. I added Weight property without scroll view at that time it work properly but when I add scroll view that time its not working properly.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtO1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtO2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtO3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtO4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtO5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAns"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" <---- Problem is here
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAns"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Answer" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPre"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Previous" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNxt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Next" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Solution Acceptable Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is the scrollView which is not getting full height and for that you should add the

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

in your scrollview.
You can just checkout my answer here

[Android TableLayout inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258467/android-tablelayout-inside-scrollview/20258638#20258638)

and just try out this xml ,I have checked it on my machine:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtO1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtO2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtO3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtO4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtO5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Answer" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPre"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNxt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: have you checked this xml on your machine bro? i have just updated and its working on my machine so just try this and let me know

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `Scrollview`.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Try like this.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot once again check your xml. Its working fine for me. If it helps you then up vote & accept the answer.