# Why My ScrollView not working Properly?

Tags: android, layout, android-scrollview

I have Two different Activities for Single Purpose(first one is Contains Elements like Buttons, Spinners... and Sec is Contains Results of the Activity). In my Activity to Display the Huge Amount of Data so i Prefer the TableLayout. Everything Good. But Now i want to Display the Hidden Data so i use ScrollView(Vertical). Without ScrollView All data Displayed perfectly but Bottom of the Screen so i get Two lines only(When i scroll i get all data but display portion is small) so i decided to use Full screen Scroll but First data only displated balanace not showed.

Activity 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#282828"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#282828"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="PRODUCTION PENDING REPORT"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </TableRow>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioType"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/type_a"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:text="DATE"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/type_b"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                            android:text="STAFF"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/type_c"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                            android:text="MIN NO WISE"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </RadioGroup>

                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/datepicker_btn"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="FROM DATE"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/datepicker_btn"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="TO DATE"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDate2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="1dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="1dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp">


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/loadbtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="LOAD"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview_customername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null" />
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#282828"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#282828"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Production_no"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="S.NO"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/S_No"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="ORDER NO"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/product"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="STAFF NAME"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/staffname"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="ORDER DATE"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="MIN NO"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/min_no"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="ORDER NO"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/In_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="MIN DATE"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/created_date"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="PRODUCT"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/created_date1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="PRODUCT"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/product_name"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/out_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="ORDED QTY"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/balan_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="FIN QTY"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Finish_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="BALANCE QTY"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/balance_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use are using listview inside scrool view right??

Comment: Use this in Scrollview tag - android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: The ScrollView can't have an orientation tag. I would also recommend you to use LinearLayout instead of TableLayout, since it's easier.

Comment: @Andolasoft but i want to scroll  above the table content also

Comment: Scrollview tag - android:fillViewport="true" NOT FIX my problem

Comment: okay i will try and come back @HusseinElFeky

Comment: @AndroidBoy use `ScrollView` in side `recyclerview`

Comment: Sorry i dont know  much more about Recyclerview @HardikParmar, bcz i want data in table format

Comment: @AndroidBoy it not necessary to your data into table format or not.

Comment: Can you Please Explain or what are changes i will make? @HardikParmar

Comment: @AndroidBoy this link for Recycler View http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ 

this link for Scrollview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Comment: okay thanks bro i will try it

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623337/how-to-scroll-table-layout-in-horizontal-and-vertical-in-android

Comment: ScrollView only consider about one item, so if you want to add more items just use a layouts. Inside the Layout, you can add anything. For more information please refer [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819189/how-to-make-my-layout-able-to-scroll-down)